# Ext JS 4 MVC Combobox

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4

I am new to Ext JS. Here i am trying to populate ComboBox using Store. I could see the combobox rendered, but with no dropdown values. Can someone please review and tell me whats wrong with below code.

**app.js:-**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
    });


Ext.application({
    name: 'MVCCombo', 
    controllers: ['Skills'],
    autoCreateViewport: true

});
```

**Controller(Skills.js):-**

```
Ext.define('MVCCombo.controller.Skills', {
            extend : 'Ext.app.Controller', 
            //define the stores
            stores : ['Skills'],
            //define the models
            models : ['Skill'],
            //define the views
            views : ['combo.Skill'],
            init: function() {
                alert("Controller Invoked");
            }
    });
```

**Store(Skills.js):-**

```
Ext.define('MVCCombo.store.Skills', {
        extend:'Ext.data.Store', 
        model:'MVCCombo.model.Skill',
        data: [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Java"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "J2EE"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Ext JS"
        }
        ]
    });
```

**Model:(Skill.js):-**

```
Ext.define('MVCCombo.model.Skill', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name:'id', type:'string'},{name:'name', type:'string'}]
});
```

**View(ViewPort.js):-**

```
Ext.define('MVCCombo.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.Viewport',    
    layout: 'fit',
    requires: [
        'MVCCombo.view.combo.Skill'
    ],
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(me, {
            items: [                
                {
                    xtype: 'cmbBox'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**View(Skill.js):-**

```
Ext.define('MVCCombo.view.combo.Skill' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    alias : 'widget.cmbBox',    
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name', 
    store: 'Skills' 
});
```

Comment: it would help if you created a jsfiddle.net example with your code

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by dbrin, I have made a quick [test on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKT6L/). I have found (by chance) that the `layout` option on your viewport is the source of the problem. Try one of these solutions :

- remove the `layout` option
- wrap the combo inside a panel

Answer (score 0):

change your widget Alias, alias/widget must lowercase :

alias : 'widget.cmbBox', to alias : 'widget.cmbbox'